# Cron Job running every other Tuesday

Tags: date, cron

Im having some difficulty with this cron job. Running a job at 6:15PM every otherTuesday during March, June, September and December

What I have so far `15 18 1 3,6,9,12 2`

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You'll have to schedule cron for every Tuesday, and then ensure in the command that only every 2nd is actually executed.

Comment: @ChristianPekeler How exactly though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a cron schedule for [every Tuesday](https://crontab.guru/#15_18_*_3,6,9,12_2), and then make sure in the command that it only runs every other time. For example, we can use the [`date`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date) command to get the number of the week, so we can check if that week number is even.

`` 15 18 * 3,6,9,12 2 [ $((`date +%V`%2)) -eq 0 ] && your_command ``

(untested)

Comment: `%2` means "modulo 2", i.e. it calculates if a number is even or odd.

Comment: so it prints the weeks number and then checks to see if its even itll print (every other week) but then whats the -eq 0]] && your_command?

Comment: `-eq 0` compares the result of the module with 0. So if the week-number is even, the comparison will be true so that it executes `your_command`. If the week-number is uneven, the comparison will be false so it doesn't execute `your_command`.

Comment: `your_command` is a placeholder for whatever you want to run in your cron job.